# Reformat JSON key/value pair to a colon separated format using jq

Tags: jq

I am new to `jq`, I want to convert below data:

```
{
  "host1": "10.1.2.3" ,
  "host2":  "10.1.2.2" ,
  "host3": "10.1.18.1"
}
```

to this below format:

```
host1 : 10.1.2.3
host2 : 10.1.2.2
host3 : 10.1.18.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the object to an association list with `to_entries`, then construct the desired string using interpolation. The `-r` option produces raw text, rather than JSON-encoded strings.

```
$ jq -r 'to_entries[] | "\(.key) : \(.value)"' tmp.json
host1 : 10.1.2.3
host2 : 10.1.2.2
host3 : 10.1.18.1
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternate version, not present in the *potentially* duplicate question linked in the comments.

```
jq -r 'keys_unsorted[] as $k | [ $k, .[$k] ] | join(" : ")'
```

Store the keys in `$k` and get the value associated with it, and put the results to an array `[..]` and join the array elements by `:`